# How to make /etc writable inside user namespace for kubelet in userns

Tags: kubernetes, linux-namespaces

In the kubernetes documentation for running kubelet in user namespace, https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-in-userns/, one of the requirements is:

```
At least, the following directories need to be writable in the namespace (not outside the namespace):

/etc
```

How can this be achieved in a user namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of the documentation right above where you quoted explains that:

> After unsharing the user namespace, you will also have to unshare other namespaces such as mount namespace.
>
> You do *not* need to call `chroot()` nor `pivot_root()` after unsharing the mount namespace, however, you have to mount writable filesystems on several directories *in* the namespace.

Comment: This sentence "you have to mount writable filesystems on several directories in the namespace." is what i'm struggling with; does it have to be the same /etc that's on the host ? or just an empty directory that's writable ? and then, how do I do it ? a plain mount that's run inside the user namespace ? or a file descriptor that's provided as argument to --mount for unshare for example ?

Comment: @LaurentiuSoica "does it have to be the same /etc that's on the host ? or just an empty directory that's writable ?" The latter. "a plain mount that's run inside the user namespace ? or a file descriptor that's provided as argument to --mount for unshare for example ?" The former.